# MS Access 2010 (Design View): return Monday of the current week with Monday as 1st day of the week

Tags: date, ms-access, design-view

I need to make my Access query always return the Monday of the current week. I have seen a few solutions on Google/StackOverflow but they are written in SQL and I am a beginner in creating Access queries (I am using the Design view to make them).

Goal: The week should be considered as **M T W T F S S.** Then, the query should always return the Monday of the current week. Therefore, if it is Sunday, it should still return the Monday before, **NOT** the next week's Monday. Can anyone explain how to do this using the Design View in Access 2010?

Comment: Does this work for you? `Date() - (DatePart("w", Date(), 2, 1)-1)` .. You can paste this into the `Field` column in Query Design View. If it works for you I can provide explanation.

Comment: Or `Date() - (WeekDay(Date(), 2) -1)`

Comment: @Invent-Animate it worked! I'd love to know why. Go ahead and write it as an answer so I can give it a green checkmark!

Comment: here something to read about datepart: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datepart.php

Comment: @krish that explained the syntax very well, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keep in mind that in this context we are working with dates, so if we do `Date() - 1`, we will get 1 day prior to today.

`Date()` ~ Today's date

```
DatePart(
        "w" - Weekday
        Date() - Today's date
        2 - vBMonday (Access assumes Sunday is the first day of the week, which is why this is necessary.)
        1 - vbFirstJan1 - This gets into using the first week of the year. We could have omitted this, as 1 is the default.
)

-1 - Subtract 1 from the DatePart value.
```

### Values

```
Date() = 4/27/2015 (at time of this writing)
DatePart("w",Date(),2,1) = 1
DatePart("w",Date(),2,1)-1 = 0
```

So we have `Date()-0`... Okay, what's so great about that? Well, let's look at a more useful scenario where today's date is a day other than Monday.

Let's act like today is 4/28/2015 (Tuesday)

```
Date() = 4/28/2015
DatePart("w",Date(),2,1) = 2
DatePart("w",Date(),2,1)-1 = 1
```

So, from the outside, in; give me the current weekday value. (1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, etc.), and subtract 1 from that -> that's how many days we need to subtract from the current date to get back to the `weekday` value of 1 (Monday).

Comment: Wow, it makes so much sense now!! Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that will do this:

```
Public Function DatePrevWeekday( _
  ByVal datDate As Date, _
  Optional ByVal bytWeekday As VbDayOfWeek = vbMonday) _
  As Date

' Returns the date of the previous weekday, as spelled in vbXxxxday, prior to datDate.
' 2000-09-06. Cactus Data ApS.

  ' No special error handling.
  On Error Resume Next

  DatePrevWeekday = DateAdd("d", 1 - Weekday(datDate, bytWeekday), datDate)

End Function
```

As vbMonday is 2 and your date is today, you can use the core expression in a query:

```
PreviousMonday: DateAdd("d",1-Weekday(Date(),2),Date())
```