# Access 2013 Expression Builder not displaying

Tags: ms-access

I apologize in advance if this question has already been asked. I searched, but did not find an answer to my particular problem:

I have a *[Date Entry]* field in my 2013 Access database, and I'm trying to add a calculated field to calculate the next Friday of the same week as the *[Date Entry]* field. I've followed the instructions I've found on numerous postings that say to either click on the empty field and select *Calculated Field* or by going to the *Fields* tab in the ribbon under the section *Add and Delete* and select *More Fields*.

None of these brings up the Expression Builder. Could it be because I have the DB saved as a MDB?

If that is the problem, does anyone have a solution for having Access automatically calculate the current week'S Friday?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly common topic, examples all over the web.

Review: [Get Monday Current Week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899253/ms-access-2010-design-view-return-monday-of-the-current-week-with-monday-as-1)

Adjust expression for whatever day you want. For Friday, try:

`DateAdd("d", 5 - Weekday(Date(),2), Date())`

If you want to return the Friday of the week a date in a record falls in, use that date field in place of Date().

If you are trying to add a calculated field to a table in MDB, cannot do that. Calculated field introduced with ACCDB. Also, calculated field will recognize very few functions. Do this calc in query or textbox.

Comment: Thanks @June7. I saved my DB as a ACCDB and can now add the calculated field. I'm now searching for a way to extract information from Excel using DAO.

Comment: Many examples in forum and out on web. Here is one http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm#WriteFileRst. If an answer resolves your issue would be nice to mark it accepted.